# Navigation not centered to heading but centered to page! Bootstrap.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to coding.
I have a navigation bar that I have centered to the page ...but I would like it to be centered to my header box.

```
<div class="header" id="header">
<div class="container">
<div class="row row-centered">
<div class="col-md-4 col-centered">
<div class="box">   
<a href="#"><h2>lewis <br><span>Designs</span></h2></a></div></div></div>
    <div class="menu">
    <div class="row row-centered">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
<ul class="nav nav-pills"> 
<li><a href="./index.html">About</a></li> 
<li><a href="./consultation.html">Consultations</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
</ul></div></div></div> 
    .box {position:relative;
       border: 2px white dotted;
       margin-top: 100px;
       margin-right: auto;
       margin-left: auto;
       width: 400px;
       display:inline-block;}
 .nav-pills li a {color: black;
       border-radius: 10px;
       vertical-align:middle;
        display:inline-block;}
 .header .box { margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        position:relative;
        vertical-align: middle;}
  .nav-pills {position: relative;
        margin-top: 40px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        text-align:center;}
```

Can you help???

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the Div to the width of the header box and this should achieve the required result

```
.col-centered{width:400px}
```

or alternatively make the header section the same size as the box.
}

```
.header .box {
    width: 100%;}
```

as long as they are the same size in width and you use the text-align center css then they should line up correctly.

Comment: I tried this and it worked!  I have the same logo on another page with one less nav button and its aligned to the left of the box. I wanted to keep the box sides consistent between pages. I am not sure this would work for every situation. Thanks for helping me with this page!!!!